# R Shiny - Display download button only upon selecting a specific input filter

Tags: r, button, shiny, download

I have a download handler which displays a download button that downloads output dataset in a csv file. But the problem I am facing is, I want the download button to be visible only if I select a specific input. The input filters are all reactive and an observe event is associated with all the input filters.

I want the download button visible only if I select the output category="Sub-Gran" as the download button feature is only for dataset2 (df_testdata2) output.

> Blockquote

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(dbplyr)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
#library(shinyBS)



category<-c('AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB')
sub.category<- c('A01','A01','A02','A02','A03','B01','B02','B02','B03','B03')
gran.category <- c('A01-11','A01-12','A02-11','A02-12','A03-11','B01-11','B02-11','B02-12','B03-11','B03-12')
val1<-c(1,1,2,5,2,4,3,1,1,1)
val2<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
val3<-c(4,5,5,6,6,3,6,8,1,1)
val4<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

testdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(category,sub.category,gran.category,val1,val2,val3,val4))

n <- 5
testdata <- do.call("rbind", replicate(n, testdata, simplify = FALSE))
testdata1 <- testdata
colnames(testdata1) <- c('boomchicka', 'boom1chicka*','boom2bookmboom','boom3','boom4','boom5','boom6')
testdata <- cbind(testdata,testdata1)

#testdata <- cbind(testdata,testdata)


## Filters
cat_name <- unique(testdata$category)
cat_sub_name <- testdata %>% select(category, sub.category, gran.category) %>% 
  distinct() %>% arrange(sub.category, gran.category)
cat_sub_gran_name <- testdata %>% select(category, sub.category, gran.category) %>% 
  distinct() %>% arrange(sub.category, gran.category)


# Server function to determine the input and output parameters
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ###   
  df_testdata1 <- reactive({
    
    if (input$Output_category == "Cat-Sub") {
      
      if (is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory) )
      {
        testdata
      }
      
      else if (is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory) )
      {
        
        testdata %>% filter(sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory)
        
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory)) 
      {
        
        testdata %>% filter(category %in% input$test_category)
        
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory))
      {
        testdata %>% filter (category %in% input$test_category & sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory)
        
      }
      
    }
    
    

    
    
    
    
  })
  
  output$tab1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
                              DT::datatable(df_testdata1(),
                                            style = "bootstrap", 
                                            rownames=TRUE,
                                            selection='none',
                                            escape=FALSE,
                                            filter = list(position = 'bottom', clear = FALSE), 
                                            options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, searching = TRUE))
    

    
  })
  
  
  df_testdata2 <- reactive({
    
    if (input$Output_category == "Sub-Gran"){
      
      
      if (is.null(input$test_subcategory) & is.null(input$test_grancategory) )
      {
        testdata
      }
      
      else if (is.null(input$test_subcategory) & !is.null(input$test_grancategory) )
      {
        
        testdata %>% filter(gran.category %in% input$test_grancategory)
        
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$test_subcategory) & is.null(input$test_grancategory)) 
      {
        
        testdata %>% filter(sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory)
        
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$test_subcategory) & !is.null(input$test_grancategory))
      {
        testdata %>% filter (sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory & gran.category %in% input$test_grancategory)
        
      }
      
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  })
  
  output$tab2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    DT::datatable(df_testdata2(),
                  style = "bootstrap", 
                  rownames=TRUE,
                  selection='none',
                  escape=FALSE,
                  filter = list(position = 'bottom', clear = FALSE), 
                  options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, searching = TRUE))
    
    
    
  })
  
  ## Enablind a download handler for CDASH Fields
  output$downLoadFilterGranCat <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('GranCat-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(df_testdata2()[input[["tab2_rows_all"]], ],file)
    }
  )
  
  
  ## Dependent reactive filter for the sub category
  observeEvent(input$test_category, {
    
    if (is.null(input$test_category)) {
      subcatToShow = unique(cat_sub_gran_name$sub.category)
      #selected <- character(0)
    }else {
      subcatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name %>% 
        filter(category %in% input$test_category) %>% 
        pull(unique(sub.category))
      #selected <- subcatToShow[1]
    }
    
    #Update the actual input
    updateSelectInput(session, "test_subcategory", choices = subcatToShow 
                      )
    
  },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  ## Dependent reactive filter for the sub category
  observeEvent(input$test_subcategory, {
    
    if (is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory)) {
      grancatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name$gran.category
      
    }
    else if (is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory)){
      grancatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name %>% 
        filter(sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory) %>% 
        pull(gran.category)
    }
    else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory)){
      grancatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name %>% 
        filter(category %in% input$test_category) %>% 
        pull(gran.category)
    }
    else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory)){
      grancatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name %>% 
        filter(category %in% input$test_category & sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory ) %>% 
        pull(gran.category)
    }
    
    #Update the actual input
    updateSelectInput(session, "test_grancategory", choices = grancatToShow
                      )
    
  },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  
}



# UI section of the program to design the front-end of the web application 

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme('darkly'),
  
  titlePanel("Analysis Dataset", windowTitle="Category Dataset"
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    

    
    mainPanel(
      width = 10,
      DT::dataTableOutput('tab1'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('tab2'),
      ## Download filter functionality
      div(downloadButton('downLoadFilterGranCat',div(strong("Download Gran Category"),
                                                        style = "text-align:center; color:green; font-size:100%")),align='center'),
      
    ),
    
    sidebarPanel( 
                  width = 2,
            
                                    selectInput("Output_category",
                                                choices = c("Cat-Sub","Sub-Gran"), 
                                                label = "Select the Output Category",
                                                multiple = TRUE),
                  
                                   selectInput("test_category",
                                               choices = cat_name, 
                                               label = "Select the category name",
                                               multiple = TRUE),
                                   
                                   selectInput("test_subcategory",
                                               choices = c(), 
                                               label = "Select the sub category name",
                                               multiple = TRUE),
                  
                                    selectInput("test_grancategory",
                                                choices = c(), 
                                                label = "Select the gran category name",
                                                multiple = TRUE)
                                   
                  
            )
    
    
      
       )
  
  
  )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to wrap your `downloadButton` inside a `conditionalPanel` which using the condition `'input.Output_category.includes("Sub-Gran")'` will show the `downloadButton` only if `"Sub-Gran"` was chosen.

Note that I stripped down your code to a much more minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

category <- c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA")
sub.category <- c("A01", "A01", "A02", "A02", "A03")
gran.category <- c("A01-11", "A01-12", "A02-11", "A02-12", "A03-11")

testdata <- data.frame(category, sub.category, gran.category)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df_testdata1 <- reactive({
    req(input$Output_category)
    if ("Cat-Sub" %in% input$Output_category) {
      testdata
    }
  })

  output$tab1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df_testdata1(),
      style = "bootstrap",
      rownames = TRUE,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE,
      filter = list(position = "bottom", clear = FALSE),
      options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, searching = TRUE)
    )
  })

  df_testdata2 <- reactive({
    req(input$Output_category)
    if ("Sub-Gran" %in% input$Output_category) {
      testdata
    }
  })

  output$tab2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df_testdata2(),
      style = "bootstrap",
      rownames = TRUE,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE,
      filter = list(position = "bottom", clear = FALSE),
      options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, searching = TRUE)
    )
  })

  output$downLoadFilterGranCat <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("GranCat-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(df_testdata2()[input[["tab2_rows_all"]], ], file)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Analysis Dataset", windowTitle = "Category Dataset"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      selectInput("Output_category",
        choices = c("Cat-Sub", "Sub-Gran"),
        label = "Select the Output Category",
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      width = 10,
      DT::dataTableOutput("tab1"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("tab2"),
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.Output_category.includes("Sub-Gran")',
        div(downloadButton("downLoadFilterGranCat", div(strong("Download Gran Category"),
          style = "text-align:center; color:green; font-size:100%"
        )), align = "center")
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the download button to appear when Sub-Gran is selected I added an `observeEvent()` to see what category it is. Then I added dynamic UI to support when the user changes the category. When the category is selected then the download button will appear, and when it's not selected (or nothing) then there will be no download button. I added comments to where I have added to your code.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(dbplyr)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(shinyBS)



category<-c('AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB')
sub.category<- c('A01','A01','A02','A02','A03','B01','B02','B02','B03','B03')
gran.category <- c('A01-11','A01-12','A02-11','A02-12','A03-11','B01-11','B02-11','B02-12','B03-11','B03-12')
val1<-c(1,1,2,5,2,4,3,1,1,1)
val2<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
val3<-c(4,5,5,6,6,3,6,8,1,1)
val4<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

testdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(category,sub.category,gran.category,val1,val2,val3,val4))

n <- 5
testdata <- do.call("rbind", replicate(n, testdata, simplify = FALSE))
testdata1 <- testdata
colnames(testdata1) <- c('boomchicka', 'boom1chicka*','boom2bookmboom','boom3','boom4','boom5','boom6')
testdata <- cbind(testdata,testdata1)

#testdata <- cbind(testdata,testdata)


## Filters
cat_name <- unique(testdata$category)
cat_sub_name <- testdata %>% select(category, sub.category, gran.category) %>% 
  distinct() %>% arrange(sub.category, gran.category)
cat_sub_gran_name <- testdata %>% select(category, sub.category, gran.category) %>% 
  distinct() %>% arrange(sub.category, gran.category)


# Server function to determine the input and output parameters
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ###   
  df_testdata1 <- reactive({
    if (input$Output_category == "Cat-Sub") {
      
      if (is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory) )
      {
        testdata
      }
      
      else if (is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory) )
      {
        
        testdata %>% filter(sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory)
        
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory)) 
      {
        
        testdata %>% filter(category %in% input$test_category)
        
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory))
      {
        testdata %>% filter (category %in% input$test_category & sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory)
        
      }
      
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  })
  
  output$tab1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    DT::datatable(df_testdata1(),
                  style = "bootstrap", 
                  rownames=TRUE,
                  selection='none',
                  escape=FALSE,
                  filter = list(position = 'bottom', clear = FALSE), 
                  options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, searching = TRUE))
    
    
    
  })
  
  # Added observeEvent
  observeEvent(input$Output_category, {
    print("printing:::::::")
    print(input$Output_category)
    if (input$Output_category != "Sub-Gran")
    {
      output$download_button <- renderUI({})
    }
  })

  
  df_testdata2 <- reactive({
    
    if (input$Output_category == "Sub-Gran"){
      
      
      # If true then display output button.
      output$download_button <- renderUI({
        div(downloadButton('downLoadFilterGranCat',div(strong("Download Gran Category"),
                                                       style = "text-align:center; color:green; font-size:100%")),align='center')
      })
      if (is.null(input$test_subcategory) & is.null(input$test_grancategory) )
      {
        testdata
      }
      
      else if (is.null(input$test_subcategory) & !is.null(input$test_grancategory) )
      {
        
        testdata %>% filter(gran.category %in% input$test_grancategory)
        
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$test_subcategory) & is.null(input$test_grancategory)) 
      {
        
        testdata %>% filter(sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory)
        
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$test_subcategory) & !is.null(input$test_grancategory))
      {
        testdata %>% filter (sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory & gran.category %in% input$test_grancategory)
        
      }
      
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
  })
  
  output$tab2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    DT::datatable(df_testdata2(),
                  style = "bootstrap", 
                  rownames=TRUE,
                  selection='none',
                  escape=FALSE,
                  filter = list(position = 'bottom', clear = FALSE), 
                  options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, searching = TRUE))
    
    
    
  })
  
  ## Enablind a download handler for CDASH Fields
  output$downLoadFilterGranCat <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('GranCat-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(df_testdata2()[input[["tab2_rows_all"]], ],file)
    }
  )
  
  
  ## Dependent reactive filter for the sub category
  observeEvent(input$test_category, {
    
    if (is.null(input$test_category)) {
      subcatToShow = unique(cat_sub_gran_name$sub.category)
      #selected <- character(0)
    }else {
      subcatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name %>% 
        filter(category %in% input$test_category) %>% 
        pull(unique(sub.category))
      #selected <- subcatToShow[1]
    }
    
    #Update the actual input
    updateSelectInput(session, "test_subcategory", choices = subcatToShow 
    )
    
  },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  ## Dependent reactive filter for the sub category
  observeEvent(input$test_subcategory, {
    
    if (is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory)) {
      grancatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name$gran.category
      
    }
    else if (is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory)){
      grancatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name %>% 
        filter(sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory) %>% 
        pull(gran.category)
    }
    else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory)){
      grancatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name %>% 
        filter(category %in% input$test_category) %>% 
        pull(gran.category)
    }
    else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory)){
      grancatToShow = cat_sub_gran_name %>% 
        filter(category %in% input$test_category & sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory ) %>% 
        pull(gran.category)
    }
    
    #Update the actual input
    updateSelectInput(session, "test_grancategory", choices = grancatToShow
    )
    
  },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  
}



# UI section of the program to design the front-end of the web application 

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme('darkly'),
  
  titlePanel("Analysis Dataset", windowTitle="Category Dataset"
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    
    
    mainPanel(
      width = 10,
      DT::dataTableOutput('tab1'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('tab2'),
      ## Download filter functionality
      # Added Dynamic Output
      uiOutput(outputId = "download_button")
    ),
    
    sidebarPanel( 
      width = 2,
      
      selectInput("Output_category",
                  choices = c("Cat-Sub","Sub-Gran"), 
                  label = "Select the Output Category",
                  multiple = TRUE),
      
      selectInput("test_category",
                  choices = cat_name, 
                  label = "Select the category name",
                  multiple = TRUE),
      
      selectInput("test_subcategory",
                  choices = c(), 
                  label = "Select the sub category name",
                  multiple = TRUE),
      
      selectInput("test_grancategory",
                  choices = c(), 
                  label = "Select the gran category name",
                  multiple = TRUE)
      
      
    )
    
    
    
  )
  
  
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```